# firstOrFail() Not Working if data not Exits

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, eloquent

This firstOrFail()  method show me the Error if database is empty. How can i access my view when database empty  .

```
$tag = Admin::where('option_name','tag')->firstOrFail();
        return view('admin.products')->with([
            'tag'  =>  $tag->option_value,
        ]);
```

or i want do this way

```
   try{

        $tag = Admin::where('option_name','tag')->firstOrFail();
        dd($tag);
    }catch (ErrorException $e){
        echo "xxxx";
    }
```

Comment: Catch `ModelNotFoundException` and define `$tag` empty. Or dont use firstOrFail..

Comment: how can i get `$tag` value like `firstOrFail()` way

Comment: @ Lawrence Cherone ` $tag = "My text";
        $tag = Admin::whereOptionName('tag')->get() ` but not Working

Answer (score 0):

```
 $tag = Admin::whereOptionName('tag')->get();
        return view('admin.products')->with([
            'tag'  =>  $tag->first()->option_value,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code with **default** value :

```
$tag=Admin::whereOptionName('tag')->first();
return view('admin.products')->with([
    'tag'  =>  collect($tag)->get('option_value','default value'),
]);
```

and in `view` you can get value with `{{tag}}`